# Is there a way to disable a contact?

Tags: contacts

I am using CiviCRM 5.7.3.

Is it possible to disable a contact? For background, we receive a list of organizations and their program ID's so those applying for grant applications can choose those they are employed by. We have to keep the data in the system if the organization closes down, but I don't want people to be able to search for it in our forms. Is it possible to disable a contact so it cannot be searched? If not, does anyone have any recommendations on what I could do?

Comment: this question is pretty close to duplicating this one https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/how-to-hide-old-contacts-from-default-search-best-practices-for-old-contacts

Comment: i know the concept of 'other CRMs have an 'archive' feature and civi doesn't' has come up a few times but not certain the above ticket is where i recall the discussion

Comment: I have an extension that does this; it's not public but when I have a moment later I'll post an answer linking to it.

Comment: I just posted a link to my extension which disables the contact on the other question [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/28485/12).

Comment: I don't want to send to trash as I will still need those records in Civi and still want to pull reports from there. I use webform for the applications themselves and that's really where I want to hide them so that the public cannot see them when they search for their organization. In the other thread a comment was made to create a new contact type and move those I need not available to that contact type. Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 3):

When you delete contacts, by default  they go into trash and don't completely disappear so you can still keep them. More info here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#deleting-contacts

Comment: There is actually a setting controlling that behaviour at Administer>System Settings> Misc (Undelete, PDFs, Limits, Logging, Captcha, etc.). By default this is switched to trash the contact.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use groups or tags? You did not say what CMS you are using or what form you are using to gather grant applications. But you may be able to create a group "Inactive" and add those orgs to that group. And then in your form select from *where not* Inactive. Or you might have to do the opposite. Select from "Active".