# How do I disable or deactivate a contact or an expired member? The only options I can find are to delete the contact, not disable or deactivate

Tags: contacts

How do I disable or deactivate a contact or an expired member? The only options I could find are to delete a contact or expired member.

Comment: To understand your needs you should explain your reason. Deleting is moving to trash in CiviCRM by default - maybe that fits your needs. But you may also configure a custom field "disabled" or set a relationship or membership to be expired. Contacts are the base entities in CiviCRM but as in rela life they can't be disabled. Their properties and relationships are the place to describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There are several answers [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14524/how-to-hide-old-contacts-from-default-search-best-practices-for-old-contacts)

of those the one using Constituents Only is the only 'technical' option, the others are mostly work arounds